# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2$ = min$_{a\in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - a)^2$

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

They ask me to prove:

> $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})^2$ = min$_{a\in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - a)^2$ with $\bar{x}$ the mean.

Well my problem is that I start to prove it by different ways but I don't reach anything.

If someone can help me giving me a clue of how to start it will be brilliant.

Comment: First of all, regardless of how far you have gotten, please edit your query to show your work.  mathSE reviewers will react **much more positively**, if you do that.  Secondly, *my first try*, which may or may not succeed, would be to use *induction on* $n$, starting with the base case of $n=2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-a)^2
=-2\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-a)
$$
When would this be $0$?

Comment: This hint is perfect. From this is easy to prove what I have to prove.